# Haskell Just iterate through list

Tags: list, haskell, iteration

I try simply to iterate through a list and return each element.

```
iterateList [] =  error "empty list"
iterateList [a] = a
iterateList (x:xs) = x iterateList xs
```

On the third line I try to return the first element and then recursively invoke `iterateList` on the tail of the List.

But that's not working. Any idea why?

Example:
input: iterateList [1,2,3,4,5]
output: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Your question is unclear - if you 'return each element' of a list you will get the original list back. Do you want to process the elements in some way?

Comment: There's several problems with what you're trying to do here, but once you've fixed those... this just becomes a function that takes a list and returns the same list again.

Comment: I added an example to the Question

Comment: @simplesystems What are you imagining the "space" to be in your example? Do you want to print each element of the list with a space between them? In Haskell, printing is a more involved task than you might expect, and is very different from just "returning".

Comment: Do you want to print the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? Specifically, what does it mean to "return" something, but then execute more code in the function?

Comment: Space could be a new line or just a space. Sorry I am really struggling with Haskell, coming from Java.

Comment: What I want is just par example a for loop in Java, where I can do something with each element in the list, like printing, sum, multiply, delete, just accessing those elements

Comment: First of all, you need to stop thinking in loops. Next, You can do all of those things with lists themselves.

Comment: A good starting point would probably be the [Learn you a Haskell chapter on lists](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists). It has examples of simple list operations, and later chapters have plenty of more interesting functions operating on lists.

Comment: @simplesystems: but in functional programming, you do not think in terms of loops, but in terms of functions. Furthermore all data is *immutable*: you can not change a list, nor its elements, nor the fields of these elements.

Comment: This looks like my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398374/extract-numbers-as-strings-from-list-of-numbers

Comment: Recursion is best used when necessary, otherwise iteration is best. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . init $ concat [ show d ++ " " | d <- [1..5]] > > > > > "1 2 3 4 5"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want is just par example a for loop in Java, where I can do something with each element in the list, like printing, sum, multiply, delete, just accessing those elements

Well, you can't "delete" anything in Haskell, and you can't modify bindings. What you can do is e.g. sum the elements:

```
sumList [] = 0
sumList (x : xs) = x + sumList xs
```

Or multiply the elements:

```
productList [] = 1
productList (x : xs) = x * productList xs
```

At this point you may realize that you've repeated yourself quite a bit, which is annoying. You can extract the common parts and turn the differences into parameters:

```
iterateList f z [] = z
iterateList f z (x : xs) = x `f` iterateList f z xs

sumList     = iterateList (+) 0
productList = iterateList (*) 1
```

Here `z` represents the "base value" to be returned for an empty input list, and `f` is the "combine" function that tells it how to deal with the element and the rest of the list.

Printing is a bit more complex because you have to know how `IO` works first (in particular, you should know about `>>` and `return`), but it can still be done:

```
doNothing           = return ()
printAndThen x rest = print x >> rest

printList = iterateList printAndThen doNothing
```

... or using values directly instead of binding them to names first:

```
printList = iterateList (\x rest -> print x >> rest) (return ())
```

Finally you would realize that you've just reinvented [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr). :-)